# Angular state.go with a stateparam not working when minified

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

When I minify all my code using uglify everything works except for this.
I have tried using state.go to a different state without stateparams and that works just fine just not with stateparams.

Router config

```
$stateProvider
.state('company',{
    url: '/portfolio/:companySlug',
    templateUrl: 'partials/company.html',
    controller: 'CompanyCtrl as company',
}
```

Inside directive with click element

```
function changePath(){
    scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log('change state');
        $state.go('company', { companySlug: e.attr('link')})
    })
};
```

Inside ng repeat HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="item in portfolio.companies" link="{{item.slug}}">

        <figure style="background: url('{{item.company_portfolio_bg}}')">
            <img class="isotope-img" src="{{item.company_portfolio_logo}}">
        </figure>

 </li>
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is working when not minified? I'm wondering where the `e` variable comes from. Is this the element inside the `link` function? If so, did you probably mean `attrs.link`? Otherwise, please provide some more context around the `changePath` function...

Comment: The e variable comes from the element where the directive is assigned to. Yes it worked before I minified everything using gulp uglify. I put every controller, directive in a iffe and then minifed it with uglify. Even when I put the slug name manually inside the state go it doesn't work.

Comment: See [Implicit Annotation
**Careful:** If you plan to minify your code, your service names will get renamed and break your app.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation)